# Is it possible to find cheap rooms for rent in Croatia, even in the high season?

Tags: budget, accommodation, croatia

I am used from my Greece vacations in may to easily find very cheap rooms (around 15-25 euros/night) to let; however this was not in high season.

I wonder if this would be possible in high season (last half of August) in Istria, Croatia. I'm traveling with my girlfriend.

Does anybody know:

- experiences for this?
- price (range)?
- availability (are there a lot of rooms to let; i.e. are they hard to find)?
- things to be aware of?

Comment: Last time we drove through Croatia a few years ago it seemed everybody near the coast was busy building more rooms for foreigners to rent. There were thickets of signs saying "Room for rent" in English, German, Italian, and Croatian. It's hard to imagine them all filling up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible. It is an economical way of accommodation in Croatia. In tourist areas, it is not difficult to find a room ("Sobe" in Croatian), even during the high season. Landlords await tourists at the arrival of the boat or the bus. You can also go to the local tourist office. They can help you in finding a room. It is possible to find rooms in the price range you mention. Sometimes you can get a discount if you stay more than one or two nights. Moreover, during the high season some landlords are reluctant to rent a room for only one night.

Note that there are some "informal" landlords, i.e. not every landlord is running an officially declared business. But that must not be an issue. I guess this is the same in Greece.

It is a good idea to visit a room before accepting. That can help to avoid bad surprises.

Comment: Thank you very much for these answers. I don't mind about informal and yes you are right about visiting before accepting.

Comment: We decide to go to Dubrovnik, I checked internet and quite some 'private appartments' seem to be available on internet from 50-100 euro, so I guess 'nonofficial' rooms to let will be cheaper as you already told and probably available, by just going to the harbor or coming from the Airport.

Comment: Note that in any case Dubrovnik is more expensive than the average.